# Display posts from another site using REST API in an asynchronous manner

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest-api

I have two WordPress websites - Alpha and Beta. I have 3 sections on the Alpha site that display content from the Beta site using WordPress Rest API:

- Section 1 displays latest posts from the Beta site.
- Section 2 displays posts from category one from the Beta site.
- Section 3 displays posts from category two from the Beta site.

Right now I'm using wp_remote_get to make REST API calls to the Beta site. Since PHP is a sequential language, the page load halts for a few seconds because it waits for all API calls complete before moving forward.

I was able to get around this issue by using WordPress Transients on Alpha to cache data I get from the Beta Site. But when the transient expires, page load halt thing happens again on the first page load.

I want load posts from the Beta site on the Alpha site asynchronously. I was trying to do it using AJAX but I'm unable to figure out how.

Edit: I have PHP function that renders HTML for post section. I'm trying to figure how do get data from the Beta site using jQuery/Ajax and pass it my PHP function so that it could render it.

Comment: And your question is? "How to do it with AJAX?" -> learn JavaScript. Using [`jQuery.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) it isn't too hard

Comment: How do I get fetch data using `jQuery.getJSON()` from the Beta site and pass it my PHP function so that it could render it?

Comment: How you implemented this? WIth ajax? Or, TLC transients only?

Comment: @chithra I did it with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Learn how to use [AJAX in Wordpress Plugins/Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). The trick is that your Javascript doesn't get the Stuff from Beta Site, your Javascript calls a PHP-Function you coded that itself gets the Stuff.

Step 2: Keep using the Transients. Check within your Ajax Callback, if there is a transient. If there is, return it. If there isn't, get the stuff from the Beta site with wp_remote_get, save it to the transient, then return it to your Ajax function.

Step 3: Put the Call to your AJAX-Function into the document.ready function.

Step 4: Profit ;)

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for! Thank you so much for pointing me in the correct direction. I guess I knew how to use the tools, I just didn't know how to use together to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are solving the wrong part of the problem here. Shifting the netwrok request to the JavaScript/client would just make it happen *every single load*. That makes performance issue worse, not better. Though delay would be presented in a different way.

What you *really* want to implement here is *async* refresh of the transient. When it expires the data should be retrieved and updated *independently* of user viewing the page.

There is a great [TLC Transients](https://github.com/markjaquith/WP-TLC-Transients) library available that can do exactly that, on top of native WP transients.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the TLC Transients. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Rahul Verma Have you used TLC transients?